# Azure Data Studio set NULL in cell in edit mode

Tags: azure-data-studio

Is there any way to enter in a cell the DB NULL value in Microsoft Azure Data Studio (VSCode version of SQL Management Studio) while I'm in edit mode? I can't find any related. No context menu and no keyboard shortcut.
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can simply type NULL in capital letters, it will automatically be converted to a NULL value. It seems to stand out from the rest as it initially isn't displayed in italics, but after refreshing it will be.

Comment: That's not working for me in this version:

Version: 1.37.0 (system setup)
Commit: d904740d93d7df76a0ba361f20e4351813b57645
Date: 2022-06-14T01:05:12.352Z
VS Code: 1.59.0
Electron: 13.6.6
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042

Comment: same here, workaround write and execute a `UPDATE` query to set it to NULL

Comment: Writing NULL in capital letters still works for me. bongio2's answer also works.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a field and use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to set it to NULL.